# Rails issue with next and prev links feature using year as an integer and not unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello everyone  I am having an hard time to create previous and next links for artworks ordered by year I am working with a collection of artworks I need to order them by year which in my case is an integer, everything works fine on index action by using the following code to display all the paintings.

index action code

```
@artworks = Artwork.where(visible: true).order(year: :desc)
```

the previous code gives me all the artworks ordered by year but when I click into an artwork I want to have previous e next links, and this is what I find it hard to achieve.

Previously I had it set up for previous and next id and worked very good like in the code below

```
def next
    Artwork.where(visible: true).where("id > ?", id).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
  end

  def prev
    Artwork.where(visible: true).where("id < ?", id).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
  end
```

now I am trying to add the year in the order but doesn't work  code below

```
def next
    Artwork.where(visible: true).where("id > ?", id).order(year: :desc).limit(1).first
  end

  def prev
    Artwork.where(visible: true).where("id < ?", id).order(year: :asc).limit(1).first
  end
```

and of course is not working because still is acting according to the id and not the year , changing the part where.("id > ?", id) with where.("year > ?", year) does something but takes only one artwork for a given year skipping artworks of the same year.

So my question is, should I approach the problem the way I am doing? or given the Artworks object containing all the artworks already ordered by year I could easily understand the current artwork and always find the previous and next , knowing all the artworks and the current one?

thank you for your advice

edit ... 
I add the full code for the files
artworks.rb model, this works good if using the id but I would like to use it with the year instead

```
class Artwork < ApplicationRecord

#non relevant model code

  def next
    Artwork.where(visible: true).where("id > ?", id).limit(1).first
  end

  def prev
    Artwork.where(visible: true).where("id < ?", id).limit(1).first
  end

end
```

show.html.erb view code that I use to display the next and prev

```
<% if @artwork.prev %>
    <%=  link_to image_tag(@artwork.prev.image.url, :class => 'img-responsive'), artwork_path(@artwork.prev) %>
    <%=  image_tag(src="http://placehold.it/700x400", :class => 'img-responsive') %>
    <%=  link_to "< recent", @artwork.prev, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>

<% if @artwork.next%>
    <%=  link_to image_tag(@artwork.next.image.url, :class => 'img-responsive'), artwork_path(@artwork.next) %>
    <%= link_to "older >", @artwork.next, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>
    <%= @artwork.next.id %>
<% end %>
```

I am understanding from some research that my main problem is that the year of the artworks is not unique, since many artworks share the same year, probably working with an array might help solve the issue?

another solution might be to use act_as_a_list and just choose each position.

Comment: This is basically just pagination. You can get the next row by using `Artwork.where(visible: true).order(year: :desc).limit(1).offset(n)` where n is how many rows you want to skip down.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment @max , I am testing offset and can't get it to work, I edited the questionand added more informations, I found out that my main issue might be that year is not a unique field

Comment: Yeah you need to consider how you are going to order records within the same year.

Comment: yes I thought that it would just use the id's whithin the same year automatically